# Python multiprocessing context change for own Process class

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

For standard Process class I can change context like this (example from python documentation):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def foo(q):
    q.put('hello')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
    q = ctx.Queue()
    p = ctx.Process(target=foo, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get())
    p.join()
```

But what should I do, when I have own Process class? For example:

```
class P(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def run(self):
        pass
```

Comment: What is your use case? If you have your context available when creating your class, you can inherit directly from `ctx.Process` instead of from `mp.Process`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So there is no way to switch context of a Process, for example in constructor?

Comment: Looking at the source code, it is probably possible to write a wrapper that does that, but again, what is your use case? Are you sure you need it? Why do you think you do?